# BusyDialog's strange behavior

Tags: sapui5

I try to use the above mentioned control in my app.

The problem is that the dialog is not showing up when it should.

Here is a problem example code (and here is the link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gituyuqera/1/edit?html,output)):

```js
function freeze(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 500000000; i++){
    }  
};

new sap.m.Button({
    text:"press to start",
    press:function(){
        var oBusyDialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog({
            text:"Working......"
        });
        oBusyDialog.open();
        freeze();
        oBusyDialog.setText("STILL WORKING..........");
        freeze();
        //oBusyDialog.destroy();
    }
}).placeAt("content");
```

The problem is that when I press the button, the screen freezes (while doing the `freeze()` function), then I see the second message of the dialog, but the first message is never displayed.

Originally, I wanted to show the dialog while doing synchronous XMLHttpRequests calls (instead of `freeze()`) and I see the same buggy functionality of the dialog.

How do I make the dialog work properly?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests TL;DR don't use sync, always async. Then your Dialog will work (open the dialog before doing http stuff, close it when the async response arrives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BusyDialog uses an sap.ui.core.Popup internally. The Popup will open animated.

You have to realize that javascript is (normally) singlethreaded. The animation events will be executed only if *the* thead is idle. Which is not the case: It's incrementing `i` like hell. So the BusyDialog is stuck at the begining of the fade in animation.